# sorting array: descending arsort returns 1

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array and when I run `print_r($array)` I get:

```
Array
(
    [XS] => 110
    [S] => 171
    [M] => 172
    [L] => 171
    [XL] => 171
    [2X] => 172
    [3X] => 154
    [4X] => 139
    [5X] => 47
    [6X] => 32
    [OSFA] => 12
    [FITTED S-M] => 12
    [FITTED L-XL] => 12
    [ADJ] => 52
    [YXS] => 15
    [YSM] => 20
    [YMD] => 20
    [YLG] => 20
    [YXL] => 17
    [TLG] => 1
    [TXL] => 1
    [T2X] => 1
    [T3X] => 3
    [S-M FLEX] => 3
    [M-L FLEX] => 3
    [L-XL FLEX] => 3
    [CHILD STRETCH] => 1
    [S/M] => 1
 )
```

I want to sort it descending, but `arsort` returns 1. I can sort it with for loop but I want the best solution. Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, `arsort` returns 1 because it's a mutating function. After `arsort`, your `$array` has been sorted. [Document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php).

Comment: Thank you i thought it returns an array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php sort() on array produces wrong result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517243/php-sort-on-array-produces-wrong-result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `arsort($icon,SORT_NUMERIC)`;
you can sort the data as numeric put ur data on $icon

Comment: it removes the keys i don't want that

Comment: `$array = array('a'=>1,'b'=>2);`
`arsort($array,SORT_NUMERIC);`
`print_r($array);`

sort return boolens dn store them just use sort and print on next line