# asort not working properly alphabetically

Tags: arrays, asort

I have a array like below. I am trying to sort the array alphabetically with asort. but it does not work

```
Array
(
    [0] => BelExpo exhibition center
    [1] => Aurora cinema theatre
    [2] => Yunost Ice hockey palace
    [3] => Rakauski free market
    [4] => Grushevka Metro Station

)

$arr = asort($arr1); // output gives 1
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php sort() on array produces wrong result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7517243/php-sort-on-array-produces-wrong-result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK great I solved the problem.

sort return boolean value. no need to put it in variable. just pass the array in sort. and it will work

```
sort($arr);

print_r($arr);
```